# Xcode unexpected http status code 402 (-1)

Tags: ios, xcode, repository, bitbucket

While pushing the code from Xcode to bitbucket repo i got an error 'unexpected http status code 402 (-1)'.

There are lot of answers available in internet for other http status code but i couldn't find any solution for status code 402 (-1)

Error image

[image]

Comment: one solutions is try to clean Your Project Code.

Comment: Did you get any solution, I am facing same problem. and already tried with reset clean build my project by getting same result after posing on the bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same issue. I didn't have enough permission to write I had access to read only. Once my administrator upgraded the plan I didn't face any issue while pushing the code.